# How do I create an audio buffer out of an audio tag?

Tags: web-audio-api

Can I somehow use a loaded audio tag to create an audio buffer?

I know that the web audio API has a `decodeAudioData` method that can be used to create an audio buffer, but it does not accept an audio tag.

How can I take an audio tag and use it to create an audio buffer that can be played by a source node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, it doesn't look like the audio tag can be loaded into a buffer. The only way so far to create an `AudioBuffer` is through `XMLHttpRequest` or creating an empty buffer.

Comment: That's correct.  You can't get access to the raw encoded bits or the decoded buffer from an <audio> element; you'll have to grab the URL (from 'src') and then call decodeAudioData.